# CSHTML : how to display an existing view on another page like popup

Tags: c#, razor

I have a page which already exists and is working fine.
Now I have a URL to that view and I need to display that view in a pop up.

Is there any other way of doing this without using an iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use object and embeded (alternate for iframe

```html
<object data="http://www.web-source.net" width="600" height="400">
    <embed src="http://www.web-source.net" width="600" height="400"> </embed>
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

)

Answer (score 1):

With ajax call and partial view.

```
$.ajax({
            url: /Controller/Action,
            type: 'GET',
            data: id,
            success: function (result) {
            $("#tagId").html(result);
            }
         });

public ActionResult Action(int id)
{

  //var model = whatever you want to return

    return PartialView("PartialView", model);
}
```

Comment: He said that the View is existed and working fine. Is it already return View() and not PartialView()?

Comment: @ThiệnSinh : The existing view is a view with its partial view etc... However there is just one partial which need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modal Box for solve your problem there is an example in w3 link below:

**Link:** https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

This modal box displayed on top of your current page. You can use trigger JScript for call this modal or just use  to link